# Reload a <apex:pageblocksection> or <apex:outputpanel> on an onclick event in APEX

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a two tabs defined as below:

```
<div id="Tabs"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
        <li id="li_tab1"  ><a href="#tab1"><strong> Tab1</strong></a></li>
        <li id="li_tab2" ><a href="#tab2"><strong> Tab2</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now on click of this I want to reload my pageblocksection or outputpanel

```
<apex:pageblock id="root">
<apex:pageblocksection>
    <apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageblock>
```

I have tried this :

```
$('#li_tab1').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); console.log('remove 2 and add 1'); jsFunctionforpp(); });
```

This is my actionfunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="jsFunctionforpp" action="{!apexMethodforpp}" reRender="root"/>
```

I tried rerendering the pageblocksection or a outputpanel. But it does not work.

Comment: did you try to write any code for onclick event? whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: Yes I tried jquery:  $('#li_tab1').click(function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();
                             console.log('remove 2 and add 1');
                             jsFunctionforpp(); 
                        });

Comment: This is my action fuction which rerenders the pageblock <apex:actionFunction name="jsFunctionforpp" action="{!apexMethodforpp}" reRender="root"/>  I tried rerendering the pageblocksection but it is not working.

Comment: update your question with your code

Answer (score 0):

Providing you a sample code. Hope this help.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

  <title>Page on Tab</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}" />
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}" /> 

    <script>

    function tabcall(){

    methodcall();

    }
        function selectTab(elmnt) {
            // slds-active
            $(elmnt).parent("li").siblings(".slds-active").removeClass("slds-active");
            $(elmnt).parent("li").addClass("slds-active");

            // tabindex
            $(elmnt).parent("li").siblings().children("a").attr("tabindex", -1);
            $(elmnt).attr("tabindex", 0);

            // aria-selected
            $(elmnt).parent("li").siblings().children("a").attr("aria-selected", false);
            $(elmnt).attr("aria-selected", true);

            // hiding previouly selected tab (slds-show/slds-hide)
            $(elmnt).closest(".slds-tabs--default").children("div[role='tabpanel'].slds-show").addClass("slds-hide");
            $(elmnt).closest(".slds-tabs--default").children("div[role='tabpanel'].slds-show").removeClass("slds-show");
            // displaying newly selected tab (slds-show/slds-hide)
            $(elmnt).closest(".slds-tabs--default").children("div[aria-labelledby='"+elmnt.id+"']").addClass("slds-show");
            $(elmnt).closest(".slds-tabs--default").children("div[aria-labelledby='"+elmnt.id+"']").removeClass("slds-hide");
        }
    </script>
<apex:form id="mainSec1">
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!methodOne}" name="methodOneInJavascript" rerender="showstate">
        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!state}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <div class="slds-tabs--default">

      <!-- TABS -->
      <ul class="slds-tabs--scoped__nav" role="tablist">
        <li class="slds-tabs--scoped__item slds-text-title--caps slds-active" title="Tab 1" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs--default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-scoped-1" id="tab-scoped-1__item" onclick="selectTab(this);tabcall();">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="slds-tabs--scoped__item slds-text-title--caps slds-active" title="Tab 2" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs--default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-scoped-2" id="tab-scoped-2__item" onclick="selectTab(this);tabcall();">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="slds-tabs--scoped__item slds-text-title--caps slds-active" title="Tab 3" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs--default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-scoped-3" id="tab-scoped-3__item" onclick="selectTab(this);tabcall();">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class="slds-tabs--scoped__item slds-text-title--caps slds-active" title="Tab 4" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs--default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-scoped-4" id="tab-scoped-4__item" onclick="selectTab(this);tabcall();">Tab 4</a></li>
      </ul>


    <apex:actionFunction name="methodcall" rerender="outpanel">
    </apex:actionFunction>
      <!-- TAB 1 -->
      <div id="tab-scoped-1__item" class="slds-tabs--default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-1__item">
        Tab One Content
      </div>

      <!-- TAB 2 -->
      <div id="tab-scoped-2__item" class="slds-tabs--default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-2__item">
        Tab Two Content
      </div>

      <!-- TAB 3 -->
      <div id="tab-scoped-3__item" class="slds-tabs--default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-3__item">
        Tab Three Content
      </div>

      <div id="tab-scoped-4__item" class="slds-tabs--default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-4__item">
        Tab Four Content
      </div>
      <div>
      <apex:outputPanel id="outpanel">
      Hello! Tab
      </apex:outputPanel>
      </div>

  </div>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: `Shweta Soparkar` Please let me know if it is  working

Comment: I would like to refresh the component not just render it. I am able to render it using my logic but I am not able to refresh it. I am trying to refresh it because I am using a data grid and data grid wont get values unless and untill its a refresh.

Comment: You need to refreshed data when you clicked on any of the tab. is that correct??

Comment: yes thats correct!!

Comment: Then definetly you need to call a method onclick on tab and when you call that mthod on click, it will return you a list of record. That list will be refresh list, so data that will be displayed in vf pge are refreshed data

Comment: My  outputpanel is getting rendered correctly but my data grid is not taking any value. I dnt know why.